# Actually run a function a certain percentage of the time in PHP

Tags: php, random, anonymous-function

How can I write a function in PHP to call a given function (anonymous) `X%` of the time?

For example:

```
function call_weighted(0.1, function() {
      echo 'this is actually run approximately 10% of the times it is called';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function call_weighted($weight, $function) {
    if (mt_rand() < $weight * mt_getrandmax()) {
        $function();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is working properly, using `1%` it is calling quite often. In my test `call_weighted(0.01, function() {...`, no more than 5 misses, before hitting.

Comment: `mt_rand` returns an integer, not a fraction. Had to change it to multiply the maximum by the weight.